# How to add a link element into a json object

Tags: json

I wanted to add the FontAwesome CDN URL to a JSON object, but it's not working.

When I open the "styleesheet" it's underlined red with a message saying.

> Expected comma or closing brace

```
fontawesome:[{
      "download": "N/A",
      "cdn": "<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font awesome/css/fontawesome.min.css">",
}]
```

Comment: That's not a URL, that's an HTML tag.

Comment: You need to read up on string literals, and how to use quotes in them.

Answer (score 0):

JSON spec does not allow a trailing comma. That last comma at the end should not be there.

Comment: But this is not JSON; it's just a JavaScript object. Also, there is a more basic problem, which is his use of quotes.

Answer (score 0):

**Some observations :**

- Your `JSON` is not valid.
- comma trailing an object in javaScript is not valid.

**Valid JSON :**

[image]